# Can the different PR regions of FPGA be simultaneously reconfigured? (Parallel Partial Reconfiguration)

Tags: fpga

Suppose,I have a FPGA with 4 partially re-configurable regions, can I simultaneously partially reconfigure these 4 tiles at a time? is any FPGA support this scheme or any reference in which this model has been discussed.. Due to lack of reconfig port (ICAP), should it be serially? i.e. I have to partially reconfigure these 4 PR regions one by one?

Please, share your views

regards

Comment: There is only one `ICAP`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to reconfigure PR regions simultaneously due to a single PL configuration Module (which is a doorway to the PL Fabric). The COnfig. Module is either accessible by ICAP or PCAP or TAP Controller at a single time.